# VIM 8.2 Backspace Delete behavior

Tags: key-bindings

I uninstalled vim 8.1 which is the available version through my package manager and installed 8.2 from source. But Backspace and Delete buttons behave in a different way in this version.

If you are in insert mode and press Backspace then it does not delete or move indentation to the left. Delete button in insert mode deletes up to the end of the current line and does not continue to the next one.

Why these changes in behavior and how do I revert to the previous one?

Comment: What probably happened is that some distros ship with a custom configuration which modify some Vim defaults; for example Arch Linux adds [archlinux.vim](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/archlinux.vim?h=packages/vim) which gets loaded from the [global vimrc](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/vimrc?h=packages/vim) it installs. I think Debian/Ubuntu does something similar as well. When you removed the package and installed Vim from source, those "extra defaults" got lost. The Vim defaults are always the same, but Linux distros may modify them.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the docs. You need to set:

`set backspace=indent,eol,start`

My previous installation was vim-gtk. I suppose this package has this value set as default.

Now both backspace and delete work as before.